# Pip Installed Tools: "command not found" | Homebrew Installed Python Tools Work Fine

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, python

I installed Python 3 with Homebrew and a tool I was installing through Homebrew auto-installed Python 2.x. So, I have both and pip (etc) is installed for both, unlike the macOS default Python.

Python tools that I download through Homebrew/Core work fine. Anything I install through pip, pip2, pip3 gives me a bash response of "command not found".

```
ImgurDownloader
-bash: ImgurDownloader: command not found

ImgurDownloader -h
-bash: ImgurDownloader: command not found
```

Pip, itself, finds these tools installed without issue and believes they are all set up and ready to go.

```
pip show ImgurDownloader 
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Name: ImgurDownloader
Version: 1.0
Summary: Download and discover imgur albums
Home-page: https://github.com/tiberiuichim/imgur-album-recursive-downloader
Author: Tiberiu Ichim
Author-email: tiberiu.ichim@gmail.com
License: GPL3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: xdg, click, awesome-slugify, requests
Required-by:
```

The problem is not restricted to the tool used as an example above; it happens with every pip installed tool.

What's going on? Are the two Pythons crossing wires? Is there something missing from my path?

---

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/Developer:/usr/local/ardua:/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:/usr/local/opt/nss/bin:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:/usr/local/opt/python2/bin:/usr/local/opt/python2/libexec:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/opt/sphinx-doc/bin
```

---

I can't figure out how to fix this because I don't understand what's broken.

Comment: There’s a lot to unpack with python since the transition is in full swing and not all packages have (or will) make the transition - https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python

Comment: I've edited to include the output responses I get.

Comment: Cool - so that library isn't on pip3 - so you'll want to run python2 and see if it can import the module. It could still be path or version or just the install failed. When I'm back at a Mac I'll poke a little more - I'm confident someone will be able to reproduce  this, though with the extra detail if they don't just _know_ the answer based on usage...

Comment: Use conda for managing python packages then pip under that - makes life simpler.:) Or download all python packages through Homebrew and don't use pip ;) OK to debug -  Now in this case what is the path you have to pip pip2 and pip3 and what is the #! line in each of them

Comment: @Mark, sorry your comment is confusing me. The packages I need are not available through Homebrew, which is why I installed them via pip. My pip paths are the defaults, as set by homebrew, no customization of anything there.

Comment: I reinstalled all the tools several times and they all appear to have installed correctly, every time. Further, I also tried installing them specifically with 'pip2' and that has had no effect on the 'command not found' response. @bmike, to where would I import the modules? Do you mean so as to use the native macOS Python2?

Comment: How about this: setup a virtual environment and using python distribution from homebrew and make sure you set `--no-site-packages` so that it wont use the system packages. Then from that virtual environment do a pip3 install whatever you need. In other words: `virtualenv -p /path/to/homebrew/python3 --no-site-packages foo`. Then `source foo/bin/activate` and finally `pip3 isntall bar`

Comment: That seems needlessly complicated. I should be able to just call the tool without bash telling me it can't find it.

Comment: Could you show us the location of your python, python3, pip, pip3 using which

```
which python3
which pip3
which python
which pip
```

Please also show us the information when you type `python`, `python3` in command line so that we can check which version python your bash is using.